# JotCache Vs Joomla built-in Cache which is better & Why?

Tags: performance, optimization, joomla, joomla2.5

Which is better & Why ?

What are the best caching techniques to be used for site with some dyncamic content like forums and Downloads section ?

is there other better options ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to @Riccardo Zorn , JotCache is better as it has more options that let you control the cache better .

Also According to a post on JotCache forums, the component works only for guest users (By Design) and will NOT work for logged-in users as logged-in users get more dynamic content that will make cache a bad option .

The Challenge is to get the best configuration for the Cache, which needs many trials and inspection to get the best results .

You're very welcomed to tell us your trial with Caching, Configurations and cache component combinations

Answer (score 1):

JotCache is much more powerful and goes a long way trying to make cache more granular and efficient. However, unless you need browser-specific page caching (which only would make sense if you generate different content for different browsers, and this is bad and should be fixed), take some time figuring out the cache times that best fit your site, then run some tests: cache efficiency will vary greatly from one installation to the next.

Regarding dynamic content, Joomla modules handle it quite nicely, with an automated cache deletion of modules when the respective content is changed, so both should work.

Comment: So Does JotCache Play well with Dynamic Content like forums, Contact us forms and Download Managers like JDownloads ?
I have no problem if there's a latency in content appearance due to cache, but does the cache break the functionality ?